# Android CountDownTimer won't work in Runnable concurrent task

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, java.util.concurrent, atomicreference

I have an Android application which has an onClick() handler from a button that starts an asynchronous `Runnable` task. Partway through, it's supposed to start a new `CountDownTimer` of 5 seconds, update the text on the page `onTick()`, and `onFinish()` update the contents of an `AtomicReference<LinkedList<float[]>>`.

Code is below for reference, and for context, know that both the Log.i "====..." statements show, but no logs show from in between.

```java
Log.i(TAG, "==== CALIBRATING GYROSCOPE ====");

  isCalibrating = true;
  // CountDownTimer for measurement
  new CountDownTimer(waitTime * 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setText(getString(R.string.calibration_in_progress) + 
               (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
    Log.i(TAG, "Millis until finished: " + millisUntilFinished);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      Log.i(TAG, "Setting current values");
      currentVals.set(gyroVals);
      Log.i(TAG, "Performing file operation");
      performFileOp(0, currentVals.get());
    }
  }.start();

  Log.i(TAG, "==== CALIBRATING ACCELEROMETER ====");
```

Comment: Are you sure that `waitTime` is not `0`?

Comment: what is the value in wait time?